# Find a formula for mathematical logic problem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Using the atomic propositions A: "John plays guitar", and B: "John plays piano", "C: John plays violin", find the well-formed formula of propositional logic corresponding to the proposition "John plays just on two from given musical instruments."

Comment: Not clear... "John plays (exactly) two..." ?

Answer (score 0):

You know that at least one of $X \land Y$ must be true, so the first attempt is:

$$(A \land B) \lor (B \land C) \lor (C \land A)$$

But this also includes the case where John plays all three instruments, so the final answer is

$$((A \land B) \lor (B \land C) \lor (C \land A)) \land \lnot(A \land B \land C)$$

Alternatively,

$$(A \land B \land \lnot C) \lor (B \land C \land \lnot A) \lor (C \land A \land \lnot B)$$

would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

(A AND B AND NOT C) OR (A AND NOT B AND C) OR (NOT A AND B AND C)

Every of the statements in the parenthesis refers to John plays on two given instruments, but does not play on the third one (for instance the first one refers to John playing guitar, John playing piano and John not playing violin). And you need to join this statements with OR, since you need to have at least one of them to be true.
I also omitted extra parenthesis where they are not needed.

Upd: I made an assumption, that in the task "given instruments" refers to the set of guitar, piano and violin.